# TextBox Scrollviewer not working on ReadOnly 'True'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, scrollviewer

I have the problem that the ScrollViewer is not enabled when TextBox is ReadOnly.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtOmschrijving" IsEnabled="True"  Grid.Column="1"HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Notification.DescLC}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxLength="2500" AcceptsReturn="True" Grid.RowSpan="2"Grid.ColumnSpan="2"ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"TextChanged="TextChanged" LostFocus="txt_LostFocus"/>
```

Does anyone know how to make scrollviewer enabled after TextBox is ReadOnly?

Comment: If you want it to be readonly, why not using a `TextBlock` instead?

Comment: Because it's not always ReadOnly.
We have notifications, and after closing notification it's only possible to add text an not possible to modify the existing text

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to reproduce the issue without success, vertical scrollbar is always enabled. Here the code i am using. Obtained the template with expression blend

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Themes:ListBoxChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         MaxLength="2500"
         AcceptsReturn="True"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
         IsReadOnly="True"
         Text="what is your name, my name is john do" Height="23" IsEnabled="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle1}">
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Found the issue and now it's working.
There was another control blocking the ScrollViewer.